# XSLT - Remove full parent node if child contains specific text

Tags: xslt-1.0

I just need to transform one XML file to another XML file with the wanted data.
The transformation remove every parent nodes if child nodes doesn't contain the correct category.

Input XML:

```
    <SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <ITEM_ID>142</ITEM_ID>
        <PRODUCT>Mora MV 1251</PRODUCT>
        <DESCRIPTION>XXXXX</DESCRIPTION>
        <URL>http://www.xxx.sk/o</URL>
        <IMGURL>http://xxx.jpg</IMGURL>
        <PRICE>6.74</PRICE>
        <PRICE_VAT>8.10</PRICE_VAT>
        <VAT>0.20</VAT>
        <MANUFACTURER>Mora</MANUFACTURER>
        <CATEGORYTEXT>Accessories / Mobile</CATEGORYTEXT>
        <EAN>8590371028526</EAN>
        <PRODUCTNO></PRODUCTNO>
        <WARRANTY>24</WARRANTY>
        <DELIVERY_DATE>24</DELIVERY_DATE>
    </SHOPITEM>

    <SHOPITEM>
       <ITEM_ID>XXX</ITEM_ID>
       <PRODUCT>Hyundai LLF 22924 DVDR</PRODUCT>
       <DESCRIPTION>XXXXX</DESCRIPTION>
       <URL>http://www.xxx.sk/t</URL>
       <IMGURL>http://xxx.jpg</IMGURL>
       <PRICE>173.35</PRICE>
       <PRICE_VAT>208.00</PRICE_VAT>
       <VAT>0.20</VAT>
       <MANUFACTURER>Hyundai</MANUFACTURER>
       <CATEGORYTEXT>Main category / TVs</CATEGORYTEXT>
       <EAN>xxxxx</EAN>
       <PRODUCTNO/>
       <WARRANTY>24</WARRANTY>
       <DELIVERY_DATE>99999</DELIVERY_DATE>
    </SHOPITEM>
    </SHOP>
```

I need to remove every SHOPITEM nodes where the CATEGORYTEXT is not Main category / TVs

I have the below XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CATEGORYTEXT[not(text() = 'Main category / TVs')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this only removes the CATEGORYTEXT node, not the full SHOPITEM node.
Can anyone help me please? :)
I'm new too XSLT, every help is appreciated.

Desired output is:

```
       <SHOP>
         <SHOPITEM>
           <ITEM_ID>XXX</ITEM_ID>
           <PRODUCT>Hyundai LLF 22924 DVDR</PRODUCT>
           <DESCRIPTION>XXXXX</DESCRIPTION>
           <URL>http://www.xxx.sk/t</URL>
           <IMGURL>http://xxx.jpg</IMGURL>
           <PRICE>173.35</PRICE>
           <PRICE_VAT>208.00</PRICE_VAT>
           <VAT>0.20</VAT>
           <MANUFACTURER>Hyundai</MANUFACTURER>
           <CATEGORYTEXT>Main category / TVs</CATEGORYTEXT>
           <EAN>xxxxx</EAN>
           <PRODUCTNO/>
           <WARRANTY>24</WARRANTY>
           <DELIVERY_DATE>99999</DELIVERY_DATE>
         </SHOPITEM>
       </SHOP>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
<xsl:template match="CATEGORYTEXT[not(text() = 'Main category / TVs')]"/>
```

with this:

```
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[not(CATEGORYTEXT = 'Main category / TVs')]"/>
```

Your current template filters `CATEGORYTEXT` elements based on the value of their text node children, whereas what you need is to filter `SHOPITEM` elements based on the value of their `CATEGORYTEXT` element children.

Note that it is only very rarely that you actually need to use `text()` in an XPath expression - `text()` gives you a *set* of all the individual text nodes that are direct children of the element you're dealing with, whereas usually what you care about is the complete string value of the element itself (which is, by definition, the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes)

Comment: Thank you this worked! :)
Can you help me how can I remove the empty lines with XSLT?

Comment: @user2739916 which empty lines?  The combination of the `strip-space` and the `output indent="yes"` should handle that automatically.

Comment: I figured it out :) but you was faster. Thanks for the help!

You need to add the below lines:
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

Comment: @user2739916 ah yes, I see you were missing the `method` attribute on your `xsl:output` before.